# k- Nearest Neighbor Kernel Regression in R

Tags: r, knn

I am using **"KernelKnn"** package for *k-NN* kernel regression with single covariate. But there is some problem and this error is showing.

```
 Error in if (!is.numeric(k) || is.null(k) || (k >= nrow(data)) || k <  : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How to correct the following prog?

```
 require(KernelKnn)  
 require(KernSmooth)   
 nn<-function(m,n){ 
 x<-runif(n,-1,1)  
 sd<-sd(x)   
 res <- matrix(0, m, 2)  
 for(i in 1:m){   
 y<-rexp(n,1) 
 PI <- abs(dpik(x) )                        ###plug-in  
 RoT <-abs(1.06*sd(x)*(n^(-1/5)))          ###normal scale rule     

nn1<-KernelKnn(matrix(x),TEST_data=NULL,matrix(y),k=1,weights_function='gaussian', h=PI,method = 'euclidean', regression = TRUE) 
nn2<- KernelKnn(matrix(x), TEST_data = NULL, matrix(y), k =1,weights_function='gaussian', h=RoT,method = 'euclidean', regression = TRUE) 
D1=(y-nn1)^2  
D2=(y-nn2)^2   
MSE.NN1=sum(D1)/(n)
MSE.NN2=sum(D2)/(n) 
res[i,1] =MSE.NN1   
res[i,2] =MSE.NN2  
}  
(res) 
} 
apply(nn(500,25),2,mean)  
apply(nn(500,50),2,mean) 
apply(nn(500,100),2,mean) 
apply(nn(500,150),2,mean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the documentation by running `?KernelKnn` and this will solve some of your problems.

1.- According to the documentation, `x` and `y` should be either matrices or dataframes, but you have two lists instead. So use `matrix(x)` and `matrix(y)` instead of `x` and `y`.

2.- kernel `K`-nearest neigbors is in some sense a simple `k`-nearest neighbors with weighted distances, so you have to choose the closest `k` observations, in your case between 1 and 9. Since you have 10 observations, if you choose one of them then you can't take the closest `n=10` observations as there are only 9 left.

So in summary, something like this should work

`nn1<- KernelKnn(matrix(x), TEST_data= NULL, matrix(y), k =9,weights_function='gaussian', h=RoT,method = 'euclidean', regression = TRUE)`

Notice however that the previous will throw an error for `k=1` and `k=2`, unfortunately I'm not familiar with the detailed implementation of this algorithm so I can't tell you here why is it failing in those cases.

Comment: above recommendation is really helpful for single result, bt i hve 2 use this in "Loop" and using this with loop an error is coming """Error in out_train * W : non-conformable arrays""" now how i can correct dis???

Comment: Are you looping through `k`? The `Error in out_train * W : non-conformable arrays` error occurs when `k=1` or `k=2`, i.e. when `n=1` or `n=2`

Comment: If you want this inside a loop then please include the loop that you're trying to run as an edit to your question

Comment: The error comes from setting `k=1` in your code. You will get an error as well if you set `k=2`, however if you set `k=3` or bigger then your loop will work. Unfortunately I'm not fully familiar with the implementation of the algorithm, so I can't help you in the case `k=1`